# Handle Click Event Masterpage Control on content Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, event-handling, onclicklistener

I Have a `LinkButton` on my master page, and want to do with it in my content page,

so I write a code like this on my page load :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Session("UserID") Is Nothing Then
            Session("UserID") = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER").Replace("INA\", "")
        End If

        Me.lbleMessage.Text = ""
        Dim lblUaname As Label = DirectCast(Master.FindControl("lblUname"), Label)
        lblUaname.Text = Session("UserID").ToString

        Dim testlinkbutton As LinkButton = DirectCast(Master.FindControl("LinkButton1"), LinkButton)
        testlinkbutton.Click += New EventHandler(AddressOf LinkButton1_Click)

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Me.lbleMessage.Text = ""
            If Session("UserID") <> "svaldano" Then
                'If CAuth.AuthUser(Session("UserID"), "20") Then

                'Else
                '     Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
                'End If
                FillDataWO()
                FillDataTC()
            ElseIf Not (Session("Username") Is Nothing) Then
                'If CAuth.AuthUser(Session("Username"), "20") Then

                'Else
                '     Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
                'End If
                If Session("Username") = "sv" Then
                    FillDataWO()
                    FillDataTC()
                Else
                    Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
                End If

            ElseIf Session("Username") Is Nothing Then
                Session("UserID") = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER").Replace("BMJAKARTA\", "")
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
```

but the line `testlinkbutton.Click += New EventHandler(AddressOf LinkButton1_Click)` of gimme an Error ,

`Public Event Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.`

so is it true that I couldn't use my code? because I just know about `raiseevent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
    testlinkbutton.Click += New EventHandler(AddressOf LinkButton1_Click)
```

you may try

```
    AddHandler testlinkbutton.Click, AddressOf LinkButton1_Click
```

See [How to: Add an Event Handler Using Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)